# Mongo db - Querying nested array and objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document structure:

```
{
   "_id":"12345",
   "value":{
      "T":0,
      "v":[
         {
            "name":"JW",
            "cost":100
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How do I query the name key? I tried the dot notation but without luck (I think it works for only two levels)

Comment: If you were by any chance doing a _group by_, you then need to use the `$unwind` operation on the `value.v` key before you can operate on the `name`/`cost` fields.

Answer (score 38):

It's not clear exactly what you tried, but this should work to find the above doc by `name`:

```
db.collection.find({ "value.v.name": "JW" })
```

[Reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index)

Comment: Thanks, i'm sure it did not work for me, maybe i got the query wrong.

Comment: I don't think you can use the dot operator on an array.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley I just updated the Reference link that better shows that this is supported with arrays.

Answer (score 20):

You should use `$elemMatch` operator:

```
db.collection.find({
    'value.v': { 
        $elemMatch: {
            name: 'JW', // "name == 'JW'"
            cost : 100 //if you need "&& cost == 100"
        }
    }
});
```

[Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch)