# How to query an array of documents in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an array of objects like this one:

```
{
    "actions": [{
        "help": {
            "messages": [{}, {}]
        }
    }, {
        "animals": [{
            "sea": {
                "messages": [{}, {}]
            }
        }, {
            "land": {
                "messages": [{}, {}]
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to get the `messages` array from each element. (Only the matched one)

I've tried something like:

```
db.getCollection('responses').find({"actions": "help"})
```

And

```
db.getCollection('responses').find({"actions.animals": "sea"})
```

With no luck as I'm still getting an empty array.

If this isn't possible, I'm open for alternatives.

I've been looking for similar questions like this one: [Mongo db - Querying nested array and objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638224/mongo-db-querying-nested-array-and-objects) but in that question they're looking for a specific element inside the "messages" object (in my case) for example. Same as in this other question: [Query for a field in an object in array with Mongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075205/query-for-a-field-in-an-object-in-array-with-mongo) where they're using `$elementMatch` and I don't think it fits my needs.

I thought that in the Mongo Tutorial: [Query array of documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) might help, but again, they have a similar structure like mine but they have a property for the `help` element for example, something like:

```
{
    "actions": [{
        "action": "help",
        "messages": [{}, {}]
    }, {
        "action": "animals",
        "classifications": [{
            "classification": "sea",
            "messages": [{}, {}]
        }, {
            "classification": "land",
            "messages": [{}, {}]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Is this the only way to make it to work? Or can I still maintain my original structure?

### Edit

After trying @Graciano's answer I'm getting the following:

```
db.getCollection('responses').aggregate([{
    $project: { "messages":  "$actions.animals.sea.messages" }
}])
```

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ac42e65734d1d5beda1f99b"),
    "messages" : [ 
        [ 
            [ 
                {
                    "type" : 0,
                    "speech" : "There are a lot of sea animals, to name a few: "
                }, 
                {
                    "type" : 0,
                    "speech" : "Whale\nFishes\nSharks"
                }
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now the error to solve is that it must be a single array, not an array of arrays of arrays of messages... how to solve this?

Comment: can you provide a sample data set with mixed data (with empty & non-empty arrays in it). I dont see `speech` keys in ur sample data set.

Comment: just added an answer with an edit to your query, check it and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated your query and now it will look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$project: { "messages":  "$actions.animals.sea.messages" }},
{$unwind: "$messages"},
{$unwind: "$messages"}

])
```

And the result will be:
[image]

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ac5b80dd39d9355012f6af3"),
 "messages" : [ 
    {
        "type" : 0,
        "speech" : "There are a lot of sea animals, to name a few: "
    }, 
    {
        "type" : 0,
        "speech" : "Whale\nFishes\nSharks"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you will get only single array, all you need to do `$unwind` the arrays respectively.

Answer (score 1):

if all you need are the messages you can use an aggregation and create an Array from the elements you want

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: { items:  "$actions."+parameter+".messages" },
  {$unwind: "$messages"},
  {$unwind: "$messages"}
}])
```

Comment: I need the messages but just from the matched action, i.e. if `help` is sent to the query, then I might only get the `help` messages array from it. In this case, `$concatArrays` might not be needed, right?

Comment: It worked, however you have some typos in the code, may I correct it in your answer? Or do you want to correct it yourself? And also it creates a second array inside the array

Comment: Corrected the typos, let me add an edit to my question so you can see the output I get with it.

Comment: wasn't clear how you wanted the output. As commented below by @Rahul Raj, you only need to add the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind) operation